# REST API and redirect on 302 code

Tags: angularjs, rest, redirect, single-page-application

I have a REST backend (secured with spring security). On the frontend I use AngularJS.

When I initialize my application within the browser (for instance with CTRL + F5), five HTTP GETs are issued from my frontend/AngularJS. As I am not yet authenticated, the backend answers five times with code 302 (redirecting to a login page). The browser then automatically issues five HTTP GETs to the correct redirected login URL. In return the GETs then all receive no JSON but the plain HTML login page as payload/content.

-> What I am expecting is that the browser somehow redirects to the login page! But I am somehow in the context of an SPA!?

I found a few posts telling me that one can not handle the 302 code within the javascript/application (the browser itself would handle it automatically upfront).

-> If five consecutive GETs are issued, the first would redirect -> What to do with the 4 other responses/redirects?

What concept am I missing here?